# Openlayers markers click events on multiple markers

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, markers

I am loading multiple markers dynamically and adding them to a Markers layer. The problem is that when I click on any marker, the same popup appears on the last added marker.

```
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");

    for(var i = 0; i < listd.length; i++)
    { 
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(listd[i].Longitude, listd[i].Latitude);

        var title = listd[i].Title;
        var iconPath = listd[i].IconPath;
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(15, 22);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);

        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconPath, size, offset);
        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon.clone());

        markers.addMarker(marker);

        marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                marker.lonlat,
                new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                title,
                null, false );

            map.addPopup(popup);
        });
     } 
     map.addLayer(markers);
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about when you try this ??? 
**Update New**
Gmap url with label in icon :3: 
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=**[label]|[Pin Color]|[label color]**

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|FE6256|000000

more info: https://developers.google.com/chart/

**Update**

```
 var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");

for(var i = 0; i < listd.length; i++)
{ 
    (function(i){
         var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(listd[i].Longitude, listd[i].Latitude);

         var title = listd[i].Title;
         var iconPath = listd[i].IconPath;
         var size = new OpenLayers.Size(15, 22);
         var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);

         var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconPath, size, offset);
         var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon.clone());

         markers.addMarker(marker);

        marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                marker.lonlat,
                new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                title,
                null, false );
              map.addPopup(popup);
         });
    })(i);
 } 
 map.addLayer(markers);
```

Comment: same, its like all markers points to the event of the last added marker

Comment: If you don't accept my answer, you can flow this page 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/click-a-marker-icon-to-open-a-pop-up-using-openlayers